# url amigable en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

espero que me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:

tengo este url de mi web que usa wordpress
 http://miweb.com/Canal-11/?n=cocina
donde http://miweb.com/Canal-11/ es un post, el post varia de numero y
?n=cocina que es una variable que voy a agregar usando $_GET['n'])
para dar un titulo adicional al post

lo que quiero hacer es cambiar esa url a 
http://miweb.com/Canal-11/cocina y hacerla mas amigable a mis visitantes, gracias de antemano por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Para eso debes usar las [Rewrite Rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). Debes agregar una nueva regla usando la función `add_rewrite_rule()`. En la sección de [Ejemplos](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Example) de esta página hay uno que creo te podrá servir. También debes usar la función `add_rewrite_tag()` para llamar a `n` usando `$wp_query->query_vars['n']`

En general este es un tema un poco complicado, te recomiendo usar [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/), te va a servir de mucha ayuda...

Saludos.

Comment: hola amigo gracias por responder, pero no soy programador, aun asi lo he intentado y no he podido